# VAT refund in Milan airport, where to do it?

Tags: italy, duty-free, milan, vat

In [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79316/vat-refund-in-milano) question, it was mentioned that there are 4 tax refund places in Milan Malpensa airport, but that question is from 5 years ago so wanted to check a few details, especially because I have ~30 minutes to finish everything:

1. Are these 4 places still open? Do they close down from noon to 1pm (like the rest of Italy)?
2. Where is the Customs desk in Malpensa airport?
3. Is it reasonable to be able to complete all steps in 30 minutes? I'm planning to go to any of the 4 places with no lines.
4. Can I do the refund later using mail or do I have to do it at the time of departure?
5. Should I keep the item that I purchase sealed and unopened?

Comment: Have you checked https://www.milanomalpensa-airport.com/en/shop-dine/vat-refund